# Regex - Extracting a number when preceeded OR followed by a currency sign

Tags: regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

```
if (preg_match_all('((([£€$¥](([ 0-9]([0-9])*)((\.|\,)(\d{2}|\d{1}))|([ 0-9]([0-9])*)))|(([0-9]([0-9])*)((\.|\,)(\d{2}|\d{1})(\s{0}|\s{1}))|([0-9]([0-9])*(\s{0}|\s{1})))[£€$¥]))', $Commande, $matches)) {
   $tot1 = $matches[0];
```

This is my tested solution.

It works for all 4 currencies when sign is placed before or after, with or without a space in  between.
It works with a dot or a comma for decimals.
It works without decimal, or with just 1 number after the dot or comma. 
It extracts several amounts in the same string in a mix of formats declined above as long as there is a space in between.

I think it covers everything, although I am sure it can be simplified.

It was Needed for an international order form where clients enter the amounts themselves as well as the description in the same field.

Comment: Mind explaining all the scenarios (with examples of matches and failures) you are trying to capture?  It looks like your entire expression can be cleaned up.

Comment: Your RegEx is not good. The first possibility (one without million/billion/etc.) matches `$ ,    .24` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional:

```
if (preg_match_all('~(\$ ?)?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?(?:[pcm]|bn|[mb]illion)?(?(1)| ?\$)~i', $order, $matches)) {
    $tot = $matches[0];
}
```

Explanation:

I put the currency in the first capturing group: `(\$ ?)` and I make it optional with a `?`
At the end of the pattern, I use an *if then else*:

```
(?(1)         # if the first capturing group exist
              # then match nothing
  |           # else
[ ]?\$        # matches the currency
)             # end of the conditional
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check for optional `$` at the end of amount:

```
\$? ?(\d[\d ,]*(?:\.\d{1,2})?|\d[\d,](?:\.\d{2})?) ?\$?(?:[pcm]|bn|[mb]illion)
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/bZ0jM4)